# CMDmessenger library

Tags: arduino-uno, library

I am trying to use the [CMDmessanger](https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/CmdMessenger) library on my Arduino uno, and am facing an issue.

My issue starts right from the [ArduinoController.ino](https://github.com/thijse/Arduino-CmdMessenger/tree/master/examples/ArduinoController) example.

When i send the frequency command

```
3,1;
```

The led starts blinking correctly, once per second.

But when I send a wrong command (basically a command without an argument)

```
3;
```

The led just stops blinking. The state of the led depends on which state it was in when I sent the command.

I realised that, when I send the wrongly formatted command, it takes the frequency as 0.

Is there any method by which I can make sure that the command is received in the right format, before it is executed? Ideally I would love it if there is a method to know how many arguments were received, and I could call the readBoolArg, or other equivalent functions to retrieve the argument data.

I am planning on using this library for quite a few projects, and I don't want to be in a situation where things went wrong because there was not formatting check.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For some extra context, I am a developer at Inventrom Pvt Ltd and developing a library for interfacing the Bolt WiFi module with the Arduino
[Here is a link](https://github.com/Inventrom/boltiot-arduino-helper)  if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example code uses `cmdMessenger.readFloatArg();` ([source](https://github.com/thijse/Arduino-CmdMessenger/blob/master/CmdMessenger.cpp#L454)) to read an argument.

```
void OnSetLedFrequency()
{
  // Read led state argument, interpret string as boolean
  ledFrequency = cmdMessenger.readFloatArg();
  // Make sure the frequency is not zero (to prevent divide by zero)
  if (ledFrequency < 0.001) { ledFrequency = 0.001; }
  // translate frequency in on and off times in miliseconds
  intervalOn  = (500.0/ledFrequency);
  intervalOff = (1000.0/ledFrequency);
  cmdMessenger.sendCmd(kAcknowledge,ledFrequency);
}
```

That function will set `ArgOk` to `false` if there was no next argument.

```
float CmdMessenger::readFloatArg()
{
    if (next()) {
        dumped = true;
        ArgOk = true;
        //return atof(current);
        return strtod(current, NULL);
    }
    ArgOk = false;
    return 0;
}
```

Thus you should try to use public function

```
bool isArgOk();

/**
 * Returns if the latest argument is well formed.
 */
bool CmdMessenger::isArgOk()
{
    return ArgOk;
}
```

of the `CmdMessenger` object (which will return `ArgOk`) to check if the read argument was okay. You could e.g. modify the code as follows

```
void OnSetLedFrequency()
{
  // Read led state argument, interpret string as boolean
  ledFrequency = cmdMessenger.readFloatArg();

  //Did we just read garbage because the argument wasn't there?
  if(!cmdMessenger.isArgOk()) {
      //Using Serial might be a bad idea because that cmdMessanger operates on the same Serial stream.. but you get the idea.
      Serial.println("You didn't supply a correct argument! Error.");
      return; //goodbye
  }

  // Make sure the frequency is not zero (to prevent divide by zero)
  if (ledFrequency < 0.001) { ledFrequency = 0.001; }
  // translate frequency in on and off times in miliseconds
  intervalOn  = (500.0/ledFrequency);
  intervalOff = (1000.0/ledFrequency);
  cmdMessenger.sendCmd(kAcknowledge,ledFrequency);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realise that's how the `isArgOk` function worked.